# Is it wrong to launch another activity from a FragmentActivity with tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity with two SherlockFragments in its tabs. Naturally I want to keep the currently selected tab active on orientation changes and when the user returns from an activity they've launched from either of the fragments.

So I use *onSaveInstanceState* to store the selected tab index and re-select it on *onCreate*. This works fine on orientation changes. But if I launch another activity (let's say a preferences screen) and return from it, the saved instance state is always null on *onCreate*, even though *onSaveInstanceState* has been called.

So I guess the question is that am I just going at this the wrong way. If I use fragments am I forced to use only one activity with all the sub-screens as fragments?

Or is there some other reason why my saved instance state disappears between activity changes?

Edit: code from Activity B

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you come back from an `Activity`, you shouldn't have to re-select the tab that is selected. It should remain selected after you return from the `Activity`.

Comment: That was true at least when I was still doing pre-ActionBar/Fragment stuff and using TabHost. But now it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Interesting... how are you ending the `Activity`? Just through back button or `finish()`? Both those methods take me back to the saved tab of the `ViewPager`. (Which I assume you're using?)

Comment: I was using the action bar's icon for up navigation by setting `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` on my Activity B. But actually, now that I tried it, using the back button works ok, the tab state is kept. It's the action bar icon up navigation that messes things up.

Comment: Do you override `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` in the Activity B? If so, can you edit your OP with that code?

Comment: Edited. Oh, and no, I'm not using ViewPager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `onOptionsItemSelected` code to the below. `finish()` ends an `Activity` instead of restarting the one below it.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah shoot, of course. All the fancy Fragment stuff made me forget the basics. Thanks a bunch. Same to Error 454.

Comment: Nice sleuthing @Eric, hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine.

One thing that might be confusing is that launching Activity B from Activity A doesn't guarantee that onSaveInstanceState will be called at all.  The OS makes this decision based on whether activity A might be destroyed during Activity B.

So you really have two cases to consider:

**Case 1**

- Activity A is paused
- onSaveInstanceState is not called

**Case 2**

- Activity A is paused
- onSaveInstanceState is called

See the [docs for onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) for more explanation.

Comment: That's what I suspected at first. But I've been running the app on the debugger, and onSaveInstanceState is definitely being called on Activity A when I launch B.

Comment: In that case, are you calling the super class in onSaveInstanceState? i.e. super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);  Also, are you sure onCreate is getting called when you return to Activity A?

Comment: I tried with both super and without super, same result. The onCreate is called when the action bar up navigation is used. (see discussion above) When back buttons is used, it's not called. But in that case the tab state is ok.